# Building FGL graph iteratively removes edges

Tags: haskell, graph

I'm trying to build graph iteratively using [fgl](https://www.stackage.org/lts-14.27/package/fgl-5.7.0.2) library. Initially I've tried doing it with a recursive function, but I reached the point where I'm debugging graph creation step by step. I'm trying to apply [insNodes](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.27/fgl-5.7.0.2/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html#v:insNodes) and [insEdge](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.27/fgl-5.7.0.2/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html#v:insEdge) functions to the intermediate graph. What happens is after applying insNodes to the graph, the edges "disappear".

Here's the MWE:

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph (prettyPrint, insNodes, insEdge, empty, nodes, edges)
import Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree (Gr)
import Debug.Trace (trace)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let emptyGraph = empty :: Gr String String

    let firstListOfNodes = [(0, "ABC"), (1, "DEF")]
    let firstEdge = (0, 1, "depends on")
    let graphWithNodes = trace ("inserting nodes: " ++ show firstListOfNodes ++ " into " ++ show emptyGraph) $ insNodes firstListOfNodes emptyGraph
    let graphWithEdges = trace ("inserting edge: " ++ show firstEdge ++ " into " ++ show graphWithNodes) $ insEdge firstEdge graphWithNodes

    let secondListOfNodes = [(0, "ABC"), (2, "GHI")]
    let graphWithNodes' = trace ("inserting nodes: " ++ show secondListOfNodes ++ " into " ++ show graphWithEdges) $ insNodes secondListOfNodes graphWithEdges

    putStrLn $ "result: " ++ show graphWithNodes'
    putStrLn "result pretty printed:"
    prettyPrint graphWithNodes'
```

gives the following output:

```hs
inserting nodes: [(0,"ABC"),(1,"DEF")] into mkGraph [] []
inserting edge: (0,1,"depends on") into mkGraph [(0,"ABC"),(1,"DEF")] []
inserting nodes: [(0,"ABC"),(2,"GHI")] into mkGraph [(0,"ABC"),(1,"DEF")] [(0,1,"depends on")]
result: mkGraph [(0,"ABC"),(1,"DEF"),(2,"GHI")] []
result pretty printed:
0:"ABC"->[]
1:"DEF"->[]
2:"GHI"->[]
```

What I'd expect is to receive a graph represented as `mkGraph [(0,"ABC"),(1,"DEF"),(2,"GHI")] [(0,1,"depends on")]`, but I get `mkGraph [(0,"ABC"),(1,"DEF"),(2,"GHI")] []` instead (as shown above).

I'm wondering if I'm missing something, or that's just not the way graphs are supposed to be created with `fgl` (in this case I'd have to rethink my recursive approach).

Comment: What if in the second round of insertions you insert `("42", "XYZ")` instead of `("0", "ABC")`?

Comment: Ah, there you go! When we insert a node which is already in a graph and is associated with one of the edges, these edges are dropped. When I've changed the `secondListOfNodes` to `[(42, "XYZ"), (2, "GHI")]`, I get the expected result. That'll mean that I'll have to change my approach anyway as I was using the [NodeMap](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.27/fgl-5.7.0.2/Data-Graph-Inductive-NodeMap.html) to generate nodes ID iteratively, so I'd have to check that the node is in the graph on every insert anyway. If you post your answer, I'll mark it as accepted : )